# Как собрать jar

Tags: java, javafx, intellij-idea, kotlin, jar

Написал небольшую програму для десктопа на `TornadoFX`. Не могу понять как сгенерить `jar` в `IntellJ Idea`. Пробовал стандартный способ с генерацией обычного `jar`-артифакта но они не запускаються(`linux` говорит что нет манифеста, хотя он был). Опыта с `JavaFX` и `TornadoFX` не имел ранее, поэтому прошу любой помощи.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Лучший всего способ переписать проект в `Maven`.

[1 - Создаем Maven-проект](https://javarush.ru/groups/posts/305-sozdanie-prosteyshego-web-proekta-v-intellij-idea-enterprise-edition-poshagovo-s-kartinkami) (посмотри шаги до "Превращение в веб-проект")
2 - В `pom.xml` добавляем вот такую структуру:

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>ЗДЕСЬ.ПИШЕМ.ПУТЬ</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id> <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
                        <phase>package</phase> <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

В структуре выше найди `ЗДЕСЬ.ПИШЕМ.ПУТЬ`. Вместо этого ты пишешь путь к запускаемому классу. К примеру, твой класс находится в `java->com->example->Main.java`, тогда в мы пишем в `pom.xml` `<mainClass>com.example.Main</mainClass>`

[Вроде отсюда я копировал данную структуру](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574594/how-can-i-create-an-executable-jar-with-dependencies-using-maven)

*Продолжение под картинкой*

[image: Как выглядит данная структура в проекте]

Далее, в правой части экрана в узкой панели найди `Maven`.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В ней раскрой `Lifecycle` и нажми на `install`.

После `install` у тебя сгенерируются два файла: просто jar и jar-with-dependencies. Тебе нужен второй файл, если в твоей библиотеке используются дополнительные библиотеки. Найти файлы можно В папке `target` (эта папка появится над `pom.xml`)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На этом все! Должно сработать (у меня лично это работает.)

P.S. Это ОФФТОПИК. Посмотри как работать с Maven. Если раньше ты постоянно скачивал jar-библиотеку с инета, потом через артефакты ты ее подключал... В Maven ты просто пишешь зависимость и библиотека сама закачивается в комп и подключается к проекту.

К примеру:
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json/20180813

в pom.xml будет записано как:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20180813</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Посмореть, что данная библиотека закачалась, можно нажав в левой части экрана на `External Libraries`.

Answer (score 2):

В IntelIJ с помощью комбинации клавиш CTRL+ALT+SHIFT+S попадаем в структуру проекта. Заходим в пункт Artifacts Нажимаем на Add (зеленый плюс), выбираем JAR и пункт from modules with dependencies. В выплывающем окне выбираем главный класс. Жмем ОК, закрываем окно. Выскочит еще одно окно, в котором нажимаем Apply, закрываем это окно. Настройка закончена. Идем в пункт Build Выбираем Build Artifact, затем Build.

Исполняемый файл будет сгенерирован в директории out / Artifacts. Могут возникнуть проблемы если в проекте есть import какого-либо пакета. но этого импорта нет в classpath Если JAR не запускается, войдите в структуру проекта, пункт Modules -> Dependencies -> Add -> Project Libruary -> Attach JAR

Если вдруг Ваше приложение консольное, и Вы хотите запускать его не через консоль, нужно будет создать bat-файл в котором прописать следующую команду

java -jar filename.jar
И запускать уже файл.bat.